# How to display a list of JSON objects onto html page

Tags: javascript, php, html, json, object

NOTE: Need to implement this without the use of jQuery or any other open source code.

Here is what I have

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Model</title>
    <script src="js.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Browse all our products below:</h1>
Name: <span id="name"></span><br>
Desc: <span id="desc"></span><br>
Cost: <span id="cost"></span><br>
Stock: <span id="stock"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

js.js is below

```
var getProducts = function(){

console.log("Getting Products...");
var success = function() {
            var product = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            console.log(product);
            document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = product.name;
            document.getElementById("desc").innerHTML = product.desc;
            document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = product.cost;
            document.getElementById("stock").innerHTML = product.stock;
    }
};

xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "back.php");
xhr.addEventListener("load", success);
xhr.send();
};

window.addEventListener("load", getProducts);
```

back.php returns the following from a database. They have been json_encoded:

```
{"name":"TESTPRODUCT","desc":"TESTIN12356879CEWBLABHDSB","cost":"123.45","stock":"6"}
{"name":"soot","desc":"soooottty black","cost":"980.00","stock":"10"}
{"name":"baby","desc":"chucky doll","cost":"7.92","stock":"34"}
{"name":"bob","desc":"fydrtsfxgcvnb","cost":"3546.00","stock":"978"}
{"name":"bolly","desc":"ball","cost":"77.00","stock":"89"}
```

I need to display these objects onto the html page. I know I need to implement a for loop however, no matter whatever I try, a parse error for JSON comes up.

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at
line 1 column 86 of the JSON data
var product = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
```

Would much appreciate it if someone could help me understand how to display all the JSON objects onto the html page.

Comment: validate your json first [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON is invalid. You need to put the objects in an array, and separate them by commas.

```
[{"name":"TESTPRODUCT","desc":"TESTIN12356879CEWBLABHDSB","cost":"123.45","stock":"6"},
{"name":"soot","desc":"soooottty black","cost":"980.00","stock":"10"},
{"name":"baby","desc":"chucky doll","cost":"7.92","stock":"34"},
{"name":"bob","desc":"fydrtsfxgcvnb","cost":"3546.00","stock":"978"},
{"name":"bolly","desc":"ball","cost":"77.00","stock":"89"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using open source project [jinqJs](http://www.jinqjs.com) 
Also the example is using jQuery.

[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/tford/ood0u5u9/)

```
//data can also be a string to a url that returns JSON
jinqJs().from(data).select(function(row) {
    $('#items')
         .append($("<option></option>")
         .attr("value",row.nam)
         .text(row.desc)); 
}
);
```